# Time Average Mean of X(t)=A, where A is a r.v. Ergodic vs. non-ergodic.

Tags: stochastic-processes

[image]

Time average of a sample function is defined as:

$$\bar{x} = \langle~x(t)~\rangle = \lim \limits_{T \to \infty}\frac{1}{2T} \int \limits_{-T}^{T} x(t) ~ dt$$

This is how I see it:  A few sample functions of X(t)=A, would be:

$$x_1(t) =0.2$$

$$x_2(t) = 0.7$$

$$\cdots$$

$$\text{etc}$$

How do they come up with 'A' as the time average???  $\langle x(t) \rangle=A$

Answer (score 1):

I guess when you calculate the time average integral, you are suppose to treat r.v.'s as if they are constants:

$$\bar{x} = \lim \limits_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int \limits_{-T}^{T} x(t)~dt$$

$$\bar{x} = \lim \limits_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int \limits_{-T}^{T} A~dt$$

$$\bar{x} = A ~\lim \limits_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int \limits_{-T}^{T} 1~dt$$

$$\bar{x} = A ~\lim \limits_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2T} \bigg[t\bigg]_{-T}^{T} $$

$$\bar{x} = A ~\lim \limits_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2T} \bigg[T--T\bigg]$$

$$\bar{x} = A ~\lim \limits_{T \to \infty} \frac{2T}{2T}$$

$$\bar{x} = A ~\lim \limits_{T \to \infty} 1$$

$$\bar{x} = A$$